# How to parse result of QR-scanning Zbar android?

Tags: android, zbar

I use Zbar library for QR-scanning.
I try to parse result of this scanning, but I lost some information. For parsing I use [this library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3978/).

Does any other library can parse `handleResult(Result rawResult)` rawResult?

This my code :
@Override

```
public void handleResult(final Result rawResult) {

    Log.v("myLog", rawResult.getContents()); // Prints scan results
    Log.v("myLog", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().getName()); // Prints the scan format (qrcode, pdf417 etc.)

    unswer = rawResult.getContents();

     if (unswer.contains("VCARD")){

            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Содержимое");
            builder.setMessage(unswer = rawResult.getContents());
            builder.setPositiveButton("Добавить контакт", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                String parseVcard = unswer;
                VCard vCard = VCardParser.parse(parseVcard);

                String name = vCard.getName();
                String fname = vCard.getFormattedName();
                Log.d("myLog", name + " " + fname);
                addContact(fname + " " + name);

                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(SimpleScannerActivity.this);
            }
            });

            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();


    }
```

Comment: Can you share the raw result you are trying to parse?

Comment: This is  result :BEGIN:VCARD
N:BB;AA
ORG:ER
TITLE:DDB
TEL:+35255
URL:TER
NOTE:BFREF
END:VCARD  When I use
String name = vCard.getName(); I lost "AA"

Comment: But name has AA and BB. vCard.getFormattedName(); - give me null

Comment: Can you paste the whole code for handleResult(Result rawResult) ?

Comment: No. I use this library to parse result of reading QR. Any QR . which contain  VCARD or MECARD information.

Comment: @Override
    public void handleResult(final Result rawResult) {

        Log.v("myLog", rawResult.getContents()); // Prints scan results
        Log.v("myLog", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().getName()); // Prints the scan format (qrcode, pdf417 etc.)

        unswer = rawResult.getContents();

Comment: String parseVcard = unswer;
                    VCard vCard = VCardParser.parse(parseVcard);

                    String name = vCard.getName();
                    String fname = vCard.getFormattedName();
                    Log.d("myLog", name + " " + fname);

Comment: Add it to your original question and format it properly. It is hard to read code in comments.

Comment: Have you tried replacing 

`unswer = rawResult.getContents();` 
with 

`unswer = rawResult.getText();` ?

Comment: Have you tried replacing unswer = rawResult.getContents(); with unswer = rawResult.getText(); You can`t do it

Comment: `builder.setMessage(unswer = rawResult.getContents());` can simply be `builder.setMessage(unswer);`

Comment: Formatted name is not going to return you a value because your rawResult does not contain an "FN". When you look at the value you sent it only says "N".

Answer (score 0):

`vCard.getFormattedName()` is not going to return you a value because your `rawResult` does not contain a "FN" value. When you look at the value you sent it only contains "N" which means you'll only have value with `vCard.getName();`

Comment: ok. but why it contain only half of it ? When I use vCard.getName() result must contain N:BB;AA -> BB and AA , but it contain only BB

Comment: I tried an online parser and was able to get BB;AA. You should also try using a different parser https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard